# if $X$ ~ $Beta(a,b)$ then what is $P(X < \frac{1}{4})$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, beta-function

I have tried many ways but I can not understand how to calculate that probability when a and b are not specified, I never had a problem in solving probability problems until now but this one I can not understand and can not solve
I know what is Beta(a, b) and what is probability density function for beta distribution and I wrote $P(X < \frac{1}{4}) = \frac{\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{4}}x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}dx}{\int_{0}^{1}x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}dx}$ but I can now go farther

and another question is, is this a hard question or I'm bad at this or I'm missing something?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Well, presumably the answer should be a function of $a,b$.

Comment: Looks like a trick question. If $X$ has a binomial distribution $B(a,b)$, this means that $a$ is an integer, and $X$ takes one of the values $0,1,2,\ldots,a$. So $X\lt\frac{1}{4}$ can happen if *and only if* $X=0$. Can you carry it out to completion now?

Comment: @StinkingBishop thanks for your comment, I improved question, it has Beta distribution

Comment: @lulu, probably yes, but I can not get to that function

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for.  The [Incomplete Beta Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) is not expressible in terms of elementary function.

Comment: @lulu thanks, I thought so, but I assumed maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the cdf of the beta distribution. There is no way to simplify your expression, and indeed it has the special name [regularised incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) and short symbol $I_x(a,b)$; your probability would thus be $I_{1/4}(a,b)$.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, I thought so but in another thought I assumed that problem is lack of knowledge for me